# Validación login con XMLHttpRequest()

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tengo el siguiente formulario:

```
    <form action="#" name="accesoEmpleados" id="accesoEmpleados" method="POST">

        <div class="centrar-etiqueta">
            <label for="">ID Empleado:</label>
        </div>
        <input type="text" name="idEmpleado" id="idEmpleadoLogin">
        <div class="centrar-etiqueta">
            <label for="">Contraseña:</label>
        </div>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="passwordLogin">

        <div class="enviar">
            <input type="hidden" id="accion" value="accesoEmpleado">
            <input type="submit" class="boton" value="Acceder">
        </div>
    </form>
```

En mi archivo js recojo todos los elementos de la siguiente manera:

```
const accesoEmpleados = document.querySelector('#accesoEmpleados');
accesoEmpleados.addEventListener('submit', validarAccesoEmpleados);
    function validarAccesoEmpleados(e) {

        e.preventDefault

        const idEmpleado = document.querySelector('#idEmpleadoLogin').value;
        const password = document.querySelector('#passwordLogin').value;
        const accion = document.querySelector('#accion').value;

        const datosAcceso = new FormData();

        datosAcceso.append('idEmpleado', idEmpleado);
        datosAcceso.append('password', password);
        datosAcceso.append('accion', accion);

        console.log(datosAcceso.values());

        //Llamada a AJAX

        //Crear el objeto
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        //Abrir la conexión
        xhr.open('POST', '../controller/empleadoControlador.php', true);
        //Pasar los datos
        xhr.onload = function() {
                if (this.status === 200) {
                //es correcto. Salta una ventana de confirmación y debería redireccionar al index con la sesión iniciada
                               if (this.status === 200) {
            const respuesta = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(respuesta);
            if (respuesta.respuesta == 'correcto') {
                Swal.fire({
                    position: 'center',
                    type: 'success',
                    title: 'El empleado ha sido dado de alta',
                    showConfirmButton: false,
                    timer: 1500
                })
                setTimeout(function() {
                    window.location.replace("../index.php");
                }, 2000);
            }
        }

      }

        xhr.send(datosAcceso)
    }
```

Y en mi controlador recojo las variables de la siguiente manera:

```
if (isset($_POST['accion'])){
    if ($_POST['accion'] == 'accesoEmpleado') {

        $idLogin = $_POST['idEmpleado'];
        $passLogin = $_POST['password']; 

        if($empDao->compruebaEmpleado($idLogin, $passLogin)){
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['idEmpleado'] = $idLogin;
        }
    }
}
```

La función que tengo en mi DAO compruebaEmpleado(), para comprobar si el empleado existe en la Base de Datos, es la siguiente:

```
public function compruebaEmpleado($idEmpleado, $password)
    {
        $consulta=$this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM empleado WHERE idEmpleado=:idEmpleado");
        $consulta->bindValue('idEmpleado', $idEmpleado);
        $consulta->execute();
        $empleado = $consulta->fetch();
        if (password_verify($password, $empleado['password'])){
            $respuesta= array(
                'respuesta' => 'correcto',
                'datosAcceso' => array(
                    'idEmpleado' => $idEmpleado,
                    'password' => $password
                )
            );
            json_encode($respuesta);
        }
    }
```

Cuando hago submit, no hace nada, la página se recarga y se queda igual. La consola de chrome imprime un error pero desaparece muy rápido y no puedo verlo.

¿Qué es lo que está fallando?

Muchas gracias por adelantado por la ayuda.

Comment: Pues el fallo estará en ```'../controller/empleadoControlador.php'```, no?

Comment: Pero... esa es la ruta de mi controlador...

Comment: ¿A donde esperas ser redireccionado? ¿que parte del código haría esa redirección? Recuerda que estas usando ajax, la página ya se ha cargado completamente.

Comment: ¿Qué haces cuando el usuario y la contraseña no son correctos?

Comment: Yo creo que lo que te indica Pablo, es que porque el resultado sea 200 (OK) no quiere decir que el login sea correcta. El 200 indica que el servidor te devuelve una respuesta valida, pero la respuesta puede ser un mensaje de error de login.  Dicho de otro modo, tras verificar que recibes un 200 del servidor, has de verificar que has recibido para ver si el login es correcto o no.

Comment: De acuerdo. Entiendo que entonces debo construir un array con los datos en mi metodo DAO que comprueba el empleado y devolverlos al AJAX para que los compare pero... lo estoy intentando y no lo consigo... reedito para que se vea con detalle.

Comment: He reeeditado de nuevo intentando lo último... pero sigue sin funcionar. En la reedición se ve el problema actualizado. Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: No sé como al final el error se ha imprimido en la consola:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload (app.js:313)` y `XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost/~jorgegarciacano/0.2_PFG/controller/empleadoControlador.php".` La línea 313 es `const respuesta = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedo ver dos errores en tu código.

#### 1.- En `JS`, no estas evitando correctamente que el formulario se envié.

Dado que el `button` "*Acceder*" es del tipo `submit` y en tu función `validarAccesoEmpleados` de `JS` no estas evitando correctamente que se envíe el formulario, la página se recarga.

#### Solución:

```
function validarAccesoEmpleados(e) {
    // AQUI Te falto agregar los paréntesis
    e.preventDefault();
    //
```

#### 2.- En `PHP` no estas imprimiendo ninguna respuesta.

La función [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php) devuelve una cadena (`eg: string`), pero no la estas imprimiendo.

#### Solución

```
// AQUI Agregar "echo" para imprimir
echo json_encode($respuesta);
```

***PD**: No te olvides de hacer un `echo json_encode($error);` para los "otros" casos. De lo contrario tu `JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);` en `JS` fallara.*
***PD2**: Personalmente te recomendaría que tu función `compruebaEmpleado` de `PHP`devolviera un "resultado" (`eg return $resultado`) y que en "controlador" analices el resultado e imprimas (según corresponda) el mensaje.*
***PD3**: Es una muy mala idea devolver el `password` al navegador, esto puede generar graves problemas de seguridad*

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!! de momento he añadido los paréntesis que me faltaban. Sigo probando con lo demás!!

Comment: +1 Por añadir buenas practicas a la respuesta, especialmente la de la ```password```.